# How to add a custom Callback Handler for JAX-WS client service in WebSphere 7.0/RAD 7.5

Tags: java, jax-ws, rad, ws-security, websphere-7

I'm trying to add a custom callback handler to a client web service (JAX-WS), but cannot find any information related to it. All the information out there requires a keystore, which was not required as part of JAX-RPC.

I'm converting several client web services from JAX-RPC to JAX-WS, and we implement the WS-Security header with a custom username token generator. For JAX-RPC, this is done via a simple wizard, where you create the token and token generator, and it inserts the WSSE information at runtime (using the custom CallbackHandler). For JAX-WS, all the WS-Security wizards require a keystore, and there's no information on just adding the custom CallbackHandler. For JAX-RPC, this configuration was done in the "WS Extension" and "WS Binding" tabs of the deployment descriptor. I've attempted to do it from the Services > Clients in my web project (which lists both RPC and WS services), but again, running into the keystore issue. I've also attempted it from the adminconsole, but it's not working as configured.

I'm using RAD 7.5 and WebSphere App Server 7.0.

How do I add a custom callback handler for WSSE to a client JAX-WS web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to find out how to configure this via RAD/WebSphere. Instead, I've used the WSS API to add the username/password wsse header to the request from the client. This works identical to the JAX-RPC configuration. The WSS code can be found on the IBM site here: [http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_confwssgeneratortoken.html](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.iseries.doc/info/iseriesexp/ae/twbs_confwssgeneratortoken.html)